# Best practice to connect to Citrix XenApp

Tags: domain-name-system, terminal-server, citrix, xenapp, round-robin

What is best practice to connect to your Citrix XenApp servers?
Putting the addresses of all servers in a client, or putting one dns entry with multiple a-records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I'd say using DNS entries is better, it also makes everything more manageable should you ever need to change IP addresses.

This practice doesn't only apply to Citrix Xenapp.